# Rails and ajax request: not using csrf working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, post, csrf, csrf-protection

I was Making a AJAX POST request to rails with this code:

```
  var new_note = {
    title: "New note"
  };
  $.post('/notes.json',
    {
      auth_token: auth_token,
      note: new_note
    },
    function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
      console.log(textStatus);
      console.log(jqXHR);
      var createdNoteIndex = self.notes.push(new Note());
      self.openNote(self.notes()[createdNoteIndex - 1]);
    }, "json")
    .error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
      alert("error");
      console.log(jqXHR);
      console.log(textStatus);
      console.log(errorThrown);
    });
```

and I forgot to insert the csrf token so I thought the create action was going to fail:

```
  # POST /notes.json
  def create
    @note = current_user.notes.new(params[:note])

      if @note.save
        respond_with { render json: @note, status: :created, location: @note }
      else
        respond_with { render json: @note.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
  end
```

but the record in the database has been created anyway while the requested ended in a 500 error:

```
Started POST "/notes.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-04-30 15:26:33 +0200
Processing by NotesController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"auth_token"=>"zJzKxPnvx5dQDTcFWi5k", "note"=>{"title"=>"New note"}}
MONGODB (0ms) taccuino_development['users'].find({:_id=>BSON::ObjectId('4f9c670a809ad20869000002')}).limit(-1).sort([[:_id, :asc]])
MONGODB (0ms) taccuino_development['notes'].insert([{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('4f9e9309809ad223f5000007'), "title"=>"New note", "user_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('4f9c670a809ad20869000002')}])
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 8ms

AbstractController::DoubleRenderError (Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most once per action. Also note that neither redirect nor render terminate execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action after redirecting, you need to do something like "redirect_to(...) and return".):
  app/controllers/notes_controller.rb:26:in `create'


  Rendered /home/matteo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (4.2ms)
  Rendered /home/matteo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (1.5ms)
  Rendered /home/matteo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (14.8ms)
```

I've not disabled the csrf protection so It should have given an error about the missing of the token but it hasn't...

**EDIT:**

after readng the two answers I have:

- removed the jquery_ui file

added this code to replace the jquery_ui function for csrf token and setting also the auth_token for devise:

```
  $.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
      if (settings.crossDomain) return;              
      var csrf_token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
      var auth_token = $('meta[name="auth_token"]').attr('content');

      xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', csrf_token);
      xhr.setRequestHeader('auth_token', auth_token);
    }
  });
```

removed the before_file authenticate_user! from the controller and replaced the create action releated to the current_user with a different one:

```
  def create
    @note = Note.new(params[:note])

      if @note.save
        respond_with { render json: @note, status: :created }
      else
        respond_with { render json: @note.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
  end
```

Then I've disabled the CSRF protection but i'm still getting the same error... so the probelm is another but i really can't understand what can cause a double redirection since the record is correctly created in the database...

Comment: I don't think the error is related to csrf at all. Which line is line 26 (the line that the backtrace mentions)

Comment: yes i've just discovered it's with the syntax of respond_with, i've used here the same syntax that i used with format.json but it seems that it isn't the same... sorry for the time you've lost

Answer (score 2):

If you've included `jquery_ujs.js` into your application, the CSRF token will automatically be added to AJAX requests. You can see that [here](https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails/blob/master/vendor/assets/javascripts/jquery_ujs.js#L79).

This also has nothing to do with your `DoubleRenderError` btw. That's your incorrect use of `respond_with`.

**Edit:**

Don't disable CSRF protection. Just don't.

You don't need to add the token yourself, everything should go automatically.

The reason why your action causes an error is because of `respond_with`. If you're only responding to json requests, this is how it should look:

```
# POST /notes.json
def create
  @note = current_user.notes.new(params[:note])

  if @note.save
    render json: @note, status: :created, location: @note
  else
    render json: @note.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end
```

But, because Rails already knows this pattern (it's a convention), you can shorten it to:

```
respond_to :json #, :html, :xml (optionally)

def create
  @note = current_user.notes.create(params[:note])
  respond_with @note
end
```

More details about `respond_with` are [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/MimeResponds.html).

Comment: ok but:

1-)i read that rails show the http headers as parameters but i can't see the X-CSRF-Token parameters in the request's params

Comment: It's HEADER, not PARAMETER. Use your browser's development tool for this purpose: Rails log doesn't include headers by default.

Comment: You can get the CSRF token with `request.headers['X-CSRF-Token']`. Headers are not part of the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour triggered by a missing or invalid csrf token changed about a year or so ago. Rather than raising an exception, the new behaviour is to reset the session, so the request is processed as if the user was not logged in.

You can control this behaviour by defining `handle_unverified_request` and implementing the desired behaviour there.

Comment: that seems my case but as @iain pointed out in his answer since i'm using (well, only inserting it) jquery_ujs.js it should include teh token automatically... and while it doesn't raise and exception it shouldn't save the record, right?